Get crowdloan contributors at specific block
I'm using polkadot-js to get all the contributors for a crowdloan:
const contributors = await api.derive.crowdloan.contributions(paraId);

However, I need to get them at a specific block. I have seen there is a method when creating the api instance that could help. Unfortunately, the object returned (ApiDecoration) has no derive method.
Is there any way to achieve that?

have you tried using subxt instead?

AFAIU subxt uses the api exposed by the node and it doesn't provide the list of contributors. This the reason why I had to use api.derive from polkadot-js (https://github.com/polkadot-js/api/blob/master/packages/api-derive/src/crowdloan/contributions.ts#L122). @dastansam do you know if there is any way of getting this using subxt?

The api.derive.* methods specifically do not have the ability to leverage api.at which will decorate the api for the block/runtime you want to query at. I think the main reason there is no support for api.at with the derives is a lot of them would just flat out break since the storage calls used are not all historically available. That being said, it was always intended to be a "work with the latest runtime and blocks" functionality.
I have done this in the past with staking, so the best course of action in a situation like this would be to work through the contributions code, as well as the childKeys code and reverse engineer the logic to fit your environment. It uses rxjs but you could easily convert it to using promise based async await calls.

The Polkadot JS state queries will only provide you information which is made available in the storage of the blockchain. It seems in this case, the block number is not stored with the account contribution, so you cannot use derive or query to get the information you are looking for.
The way you get this information instead is to api.at query, that you linked to in your post, and to check the transactions of that block, and filter down the transactions or events to find the ones you are looking for. You will need to do this across all blocks.
The other option is to use a block explorer like Subscan to retrieve all contributions and dates. Here is an example:
https://polkadot.subscan.io/crowdloan/2032-15
I also bet if you look at the public repositories of other Parachain teams, you will find code which they used to do the same thing to help distribute their tokens.
